# Mouse keeps freezing ramdomly

Tags: mouse, freeze

I used this command to see if my pc can locate my mouse;

> xsetpointer -1 | grep Pointer

reponse is

> Extended device -1 not found

My question is did I type in the right command or is there something else I can do to locate the mouse.

I'm using a usb gateway mouse, I'm not sure if the problem is coming from my usb slots or the mouse itself.

> apt-cache search mouse settings
>   gnome-settings-daemon - daemon handling the GNOME session settings
>   xserver-xorg-input-synaptics - Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
>   gnome-applets - Various applets for the GNOME panel - binary files
>   hama-slide-mouse-control - Control the DPI setting and thumb buttons of a Hama SLide S1 gaming mouse
>   kephra - gui text editor along Perl alike Paradigms
>   libgpds-dbg - library for configuration of pointing devices (debug symbols)
>   libjs-flot - plotting library for jQuery
>   lxinput - program to configure keyboard and mouse settings for LXDE
>   lxsession - default session manager for LXDE
>   tint2 - lightweight taskbar
>   tint2-dbg - lightweight taskbar (debug symbols)
>   wmix - Dockapp mixer for OSS
>   wmlongrun - A program to monitor longrun status
>   xfce4-settings - graphical application for managing Xfce settings
>   xkbset - Small utility to change the AccessX settings of XKEYBOARD
>   xwit - collection of simple routines to call some X11 functions

Updated:

This is the reading I'm getting from search settings.

Comment: I am getting the same exact problem... In each newer Ubuntu version, it becomes more frequent. I've had to downgrade to version 12.04, but the problem still exists. I have tried multiple mice.

Comment: I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).